# Can an Execution be related to more than one Job on Activiti BPM?

Tags: alfresco, activiti, business-process-management

I'am working with Activiti (5.22.0) and i want to retrieve a Job (table ACT_RU_JOB) by it's Execution_id (table ACT_RU_EXECUTION).
I found that i have more than one job on my activiti DB that share the same Execution ID !
It's my DB corrupted ? or effectively can multiple Jobs have the same execution id.

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Answer (score 3):

A runtime execution can (and will) often have multiple jobs asociated with it.
If any of the tasks are flagged asynchronous or you have timer or signal events in your flow, you will get a new job for each. All these jobs will be associated with the one execution.